# Jenkins master landing page

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, jenkins-cli

I am working on a landing page for a Jenkins Multi master. I would like to know if there is a way to access the build executor status view. I would like to display the names and progress of the builds currently running on the nodes on the landing page